# How do I like a YouTube video while in full screen mode?

Tags: youtube

How can I like a YouTube video while it's in full screen mode?

I can't see any buttons to do so, and this unofficial guide to [keyboard shortcuts](https://sites.google.com/a/umich.edu/going-google/accessibility/google-keyboard-shortcuts---youtube) doesn't mention liking a video.

Comment: The "scroll the screen while in full-screen" answer below solves this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually can like a video while in fullscreen. At least I am able to. Found it by accident after having given up long ago. While in fullscreen, scroll up on the window (I'm using a Macbook pro with Chrome & using two-finger scroll on touch pad), this will bring up the usual YouTube buttons, comments and side vids! You can like the video and scroll back up to continue watching in fullscreen.

Comment: This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

YouTube removed that feature long back. You can only like the video by leaving the fullscreen now

Answer (score 1):

After watching video you can press ESC and click on thumsup below video.

Comment: This is not very helpful.

Comment: it is the only true answer though @jonsca. There currently is no way to like a video on YouTube while in full screen.